# Changing model's data with new data on backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a form

```
<form>
<input id = "one" class = "number">
<input id = "two" class = "number">
<input id = "three" class = "number">
<input id = "four" class = "number">
</form>
```

in a model.

I have a button which has the following function:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var mynumber = $("#one").val() + $("#two").val() + $("#three").val();

this.model.set(mynumber);
this.model.save({},{
    success: function(model, response) {
        console.log('success! ' + response);
    },
    error: function(model, response) {
        console.log('error! ' + response);
    }
});

});
```

The problem is the function is doing a post request of all form elements(one, two, three and four). I want to have mynumber in the post request not those individual elements.

Am i doing something wrong? Do i need to create a new model or Can I not update the model with my new data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default model.save will send all the attributes you have stored in model. If you just want to put mynumber, I would suggest create a separate new model. You can achieve the same by overriding model's sync method, but that's an overkill for given purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing input values

```
var mynumber = parseFloat($("#one").val() )+parseFloat($("#two").val() )+ parseFloat($('#three').val());
```